# GIT SVN Author name not found in authors.txt

Tags: migration, git-svn, author

I was trying to migrate an svn repo with history which was working fine but when it comes to the final few revisions it says a name in author.txt not found (due to case sensitivity issue).
It took almost 2.5 days to reach this point.

Is there a way after updating author.txt, we can continue the process from the last state or we have to start it again from starting?

If there is a way to continue it.. please mention the commands and step.

Thanks